# How to set the working directory of unit test

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, xunit

My c# project looks like:

```
${workspaceFolder}/
L program/
  L bin
  L obj
  L myproject.csproj
  L program.cs
  L input.txt
L tests/
  L bin
  L obj
  L mytests.csproj
  L tests.cs
L mysolution.sln
```

In c#, I open the input.txt file using something like:
`File.ReadAllLines("program/input.txt");`
This works fine.

When running xunit tests opening the file fails with an error similar to:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '.../tests/bin/Debug/net7.0/program/input.txt'.

How can I tell VSCode to run my tests with ${workspaceFolder} as the current working directory?

VSCode: v1.78.2 / x64

c# Dev Kit: v0.1.83

c# Base Language Support: v2.0.206

Did extensive Google search and looked at all the testing settings, but can't figure this one out.
Saw answers that solved this in code using `Assembly.Location`.
I am looking for a more elegant way to use the same relative path in running build/debug and test mode.
Thank you.

Comment: You should not use real files in unit tests. Use [System.IO.Abstractions](https://github.com/TestableIO/System.IO.Abstractions) and mock IO.